# How can I start Ubuntu One when OS X starts?

Tags: ubuntu-one, macosx

Ubuntu One is not started automatically when my Mac OS X starts. Can I add it manually to the operating system start up?

Answer (score 0):

It currently doesn't start automatically. You can add it yourself using the instructions on this page: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11177?viewlocale=en_US